# Embedding $(\mathbb{R},+)$ into $(\text{Sym}(\omega),\circ)$

Tags: group-theory, set-theory

Is there an injective group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ into $(\text{Sym}(\omega),\circ)$, where $\text{Sym}$ denotes the set of all bijections $f:\omega\to\omega$? If not, is there a group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ into $(\text{Sym}(\omega),\circ)$ with countable kernel?

Comment: The answer is yes. Probably better fits in MathSE. Every abelian group of cardinal $\le c$ embeds into $Sym(\omega)$. In the torsion-free case a proof is in my answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/301875/14094 to a question of yours.

Comment: By the way a better way of thinking of $\mathbf{R}$ as an abstract group is as a vector space over $\mathbf{Q}$ of dimension $c$, or as a (unrestricted) direct product of $\omega$ copies of $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks @YCor - can you post the comments as an answer so we can close this question?

Comment: It's my principle not to answer off-topic questions as this should be discouraged. I'll post an answer if it's moved to MathSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an abstract group, $\mathbf{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}^\omega$.

Since $\mathrm{Sym}(\omega)^\omega$ embeds into $\mathrm{Sym}(\omega^2)\simeq\mathrm{Sym}(\omega)$, we deduce that any countable (unrestricted) direct product of countable groups embeds into $\mathrm{Sym}(\omega)$.

Actually any abelian group of cardinal $\le c$ embeds into $\mathrm{Sym}(\omega)$.

Comment: Probly I'm just stupid, but why is $\Bbb R\approx\Bbb Q^\omega$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich these are two vectors spaces over $\mathbf{Q}$, both of cardinal $c$, and hence both of dimension $c$.

Comment: Sure enough I was just being stupid.